# Apache shutting down unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2, shutdown, spam-prevention

I have a mongrel server running behind Apache. It works fine; however, every now and then the Apache server shuts downs seemingly by itself. I'm not sure if there is configuration issue or if it's an attack. Here is Apache error log:

```
[Thu Apr 30 02:15:07 2009] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Apr 30 02:15:07 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 30 02:15:07 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 30 02:17:13 2009] [error] [client 61.139.105.163] File does not exist: /var/www/fastenv
[Thu Apr 30 02:24:06 2009] [error] [client 61.139.105.163] File does not exist: /var/www/fastenv
[Thu Apr 30 10:49:18 2009] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Apr 30 10:49:18 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 30 12:53:08 2009] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Apr 30 12:53:08 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 30 12:53:08 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 30 12:59:15 2009] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Apr 30 12:59:15 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 30 12:59:15 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 30 13:58:49 2009] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Thu Apr 30 13:58:49 2009] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Apr 30 13:58:49 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 01 10:59:07 2009] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri May 01 10:59:07 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 01 17:51:15 2009] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri May 01 17:51:15 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Debian) PHP/5.2.0-8+etch13 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Not quite sure what is /var/www/fastenv but I don't think there is anything in my application that calls that. Also, website is still in Beta mode with few users and I don't think any have 61.139.105.163 IP address but it's possible that they might have it.

Any ideas? It would be good if you can give me hints where to look or how to go about anaysing this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same log from the same IP.  Looking it up shows it to belong to the Chinese government.  It appears to be a scan using server side includes to find out as much as they can about your server.  I banned the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is entirely programming-related, but anyway... none of those look like serious errors to me. The accesses to `/var/www/fastenv` just mean that the computer at IP address 61.139.105.163 sent a request for `http://www.example.com/fastenv` or something like that (it depends on exactly how you've configured your virtual hosts); I'd look at the access log for more information, to see what other requests have been coming from that IP address. It's probably not anything to worry about.

The line about `NameVirtualHost *:0` means that somewhere in your configuration file you have an incorrect `NameVirtualHost` directive, maybe with no arguments. You should probably look for that and remove it, but if the server is running fine anyway, it's not a big deal.

The reason your server is terminating (restarting, actually) appears to be a SIGHUP - that is, something on the system is sending Apache a signal telling it to restart. It's basically the same thing that happens if you run `apache2 restart`, I think.  Without knowing what's sending that signal, there's not more I can say.

Answer (score 0):

61.139.105.163 is known for doing all kinds of hacking type things, just google the IP address. You should definitly ban this IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Apache Config --> Apache(httpd.conf)

Search for *#Listen 12.34.56.78:80* and replace it with *#Listen 12.34.56.78:8081*.

Search for *Listen 80* and replace it with *Listen 8081*.

Now you can start Apache now, and can run it with this URL: `localhost:8081/xampp/`

Comment: I don't think this necessarily answers the question - Can you provide some more explanation as to why you suggest changing these things? The original asker doesn't seem to mention localhost or xampp in their question.