# Routing error for Started GET "/fastenv"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ip

I have been getting a lot these in my log which is causing a lot of problems. Im not even able to access certain pages in my RoR application. Any ideas?

```
Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.72.138 at 2011-05-25 08:45:37 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):

Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.88.250 at 2011-05-25 08:46:02 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):

Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.88.250 at 2011-05-25 08:46:11 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):

Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.131.74 at 2011-05-25 08:46:39 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):

Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.88.250 at 2011-05-25 08:47:24 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):

Started GET "/fastenv" for 98.126.131.74 at 2011-05-25 08:47:24 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/fastenv"):
```

Pls help!

Comment: PS: /fastenv has not got anything to do with my application.
Even this guy seems to have the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813876/apache-shutting-down-unexpectedly

Comment: now im getting new requests like "/special_for_galf_http_header.php" ,
 "/minimall?w=468&h=90&client=boresxee&sid=Chitika%20Default&cid=Chitika%20Default&...", "/TagPublish/getjs.aspx?action=VIEWAD&cwrun=200.." which dont have nethin do with my app. do u want me to route these too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These /fastenv requests seem to come from some spammer-like activities. You may create this file in your public folder (to save your server from trying to match a controller and action each time), or just ignore these errors.

You should not be scared by these errors. They are nothing unusual in the big, bad Internet. Your application is just scanned by someone in search for some exploitable errors.

You don't have to do anything. Just write your code with security in mind.

About your 500 error. There MUST be something in the logfile, unless the request has not hit your Rails application. Do you have any other server in front of your app? Apache? Nginx? Check the logfiles created by these servers.

Comment: regarding the pages, for eg when I go to myapp/home I get an error 500 and when I check the log it looks like what i have mentioned above.
Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: Do you have tests? Functional ones should detect this type of error.